# Which is hardest: iron, brass or bone?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I was hopping around random wikipedia articles when I came across the article for the [Behemoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behemoth#Description). In the description for the beast it says:

> His bones are as strong pieces of brass; his bones are like bars of
>   iron

So it got me thinking, **which of these three substances is hardest: iron, brass or bone?**

(I had a quick look at the Mohs scale, which lists iron as 4, but could not find anything for brass or bone.)

Comment: Please note that the general meaning of "hardness" is much broader than the Mohs scale, which basically measures "resistance to scratches". [Hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardness) includes  ductility, elastic stiffness, plasticity, strain, strength, toughness, viscoelasticity, and viscosity (list copied from Wikipedia), all of which have specific meanings and little to do with Mohs hardness.

Comment: There is quite a difference between a strong material and a hard material.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_of_materials

Comment: @GuntramBlohm I think if I asked for all those things the question would be closed as too broad.

Comment: @Johannes_B It's probably a bit late in the day to change the question, so I'll make do with this now. It's clear not that many people are interested anyway.

Comment: Thought this was interesting: Modulus of rigidity.  Bronze is higher than iron which raises a question.  Why did iron tools replace bronze tools.  Suspicion: iron is more flexible (less brittle?).  (Some sources saying that the problem with bronze is the need to make an alloy, but no advantage in the edge, hardness or moduli.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two sources both put bone at a hardness of 5:

http://www.chacha.com/question/how-hard-is-bone-according-to-moh's-hardness-scale

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110310200841AABwtMj

Whether they are trustworthy is questionable though, so take it as you will.

This source put brass at 3 and iron at 4.5:

http://www.jewelrynotes.com/the-mohs-scale-of-hardness-for-metals-why-it-is-important/

and this image puts brass at 4 and iron at 4-5 (Similar to 4.5):
http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/WO2001048807A1/imgf000009_0001.png

While these different sources seem to have conflicting data, I think it would be safe to assume that Brass is the softest of these three materials, Iron comes second, and Bone is the hardest.

Edit: In the description of that monster, the adjective used is 'strong'. You may want to consider how much force each of these materials can withstand instead of how hard they each are :)

Comment: Bone is primarily composed of hydroxyapatite. Note that the apatite minerals *define* the value 5 on the Mohs scale.

Comment: Right; the composite material (bone) is much better for load bearing vs weight, and scratching it is not an issue.